# MYSQL Getting all values for a GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

DB has 3 columns (thing1, thing2, datetime).  What I want to do is pull all the records for thing1 that has more than 1 unique thing2 entry for it.

```
SELECT thing1,thing2 FROM db WHERE datetime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) GROUP BY thing1 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(thing2)) > 1;
```

Gets me almost what I need but of course the "GROUP BY" makes it so it only returns 1 entry for the thing1 column, but I need all the thing1,thing2 entries.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: subquery to find the thing1's you want, then join to find the records for those thing1 values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use group by this way

```
SELECT thing1,thing2 
FROM db WHERE datetime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) 
GROUP BY thing1, thing2  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: This isn't going to work -- it could easily return a thing1 without multiple thing2 records : `pull all the records for thing1 that has more than 1 unique thing2`... This just checks more than one unique date...

Comment: That will give the combinations of thing1, thing2 that appear more than once, not the thing1 records that have more than one thing2 value. Edit: @sgeddes, it doesn't even care if the date is unique.

Comment: @Uueerdo -- good point, the date times may actually be the same, as long as multiple exist.

Comment: Ah, yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Shamelessly copying Matt S' original answer as a starting point to provide an alternative...

```
SELECT db.thing1, db.thing2 
FROM db 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT thing1, MIN(`datetime`) As `datetime` 
    FROM db 
    WHERE `datetime` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) 
    GROUP BY thing1 
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT thing2) > 1
) AS subQ ON db.thing1 = subQ.thing1 AND db.`datetime` >= subQ.`datetime`
;
```

MySQL is very finicky, performance-wise, when it comes to subqueries in `WHERE` clauses; this `JOIN` alternative *may* perform faster than such a query.

It may also perform faster, than in it's current form, with the `MIN` removed from the subquery (and the join condition), and a redundant datetime condition on the outer `WHERE` supplied instead.

Which is best will depend on data, hardware, configuration, etc...

Sidenote: I would caution against using keywords such as `datetime` as field (or table) names; they tend to bite their user when least expected, and at very least should always be escaped with ` as in the example.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're looking for, you'll want to use your current query as a sub-query:

```
SELECT thing1, thing2 FROM db WHERE thing1 IN (
    SELECT thing1 FROM db 
    WHERE datetime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) 
    GROUP BY thing1 
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT thing2) > 1
);
```

The subquery is already getting the `thing1`s you want, so this lets you get the original rows back from the table, limited to just those `thing1`s.

Comment: True. Extra parenthesis has no affect on the query anyway.

Comment: yeah, I deleted my original comment (which I was editing when you fixed that). They wouldn't have hurt the query, but I've seen plenty of people mislead by what they imply.

Comment: This could work, but it might return incorrect results as well under certain circumstances.  Since the outer query isn't limiting the results from the date, it's possible there are records with thing2 prior to that date, but they would still be returned without that extra check...  Still a better solution that the other answer and not sure if that even matters.

Comment: @sgeddes You're right, you can just add the extra check in the outer where.